# Is a curve whose derivative has constant length a geodesic?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic, connections

Given a (complete) riemannian Manifold $(M,g)$ and a curve $\gamma \colon [0,1] \to M$ with $$g\big( \dot{\gamma} (t) , \dot{\gamma}(t) \big) = C \quad \forall t \in [0,1]$$
where $C \neq 0$ is some constant. Does that automatically imply that $\gamma$ is a geodesic? Or are there counterexamples? 
 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can reparametrize a curve to have constant "speed"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: consider $(\mathbb{R}^2,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the usual dot product, and $\gamma:\theta\mapsto(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$. Then $||\gamma'(\theta)||^2=1$ but $\gamma$ is not a geodesic of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which are the straight lines.